# Python bitwise AND on multiple numbers, faster way than iterative bitwise operator?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a fastest way (`O(n^2)` is not acceptable) to apply an `AND` operator over more than 2 numbers in `Python`.

There are two scenarios:
*a)* on input we have numbers in a range between M and N
*b)* there can be a set of any natural numbers

Currently my code uses an `& operator` in a loop, which always compute a result bit (despite the fact that we know, that if we have `0`, than the next and all next result bits will always be `0`). One of my ideas is to compute bits per columns, and for a given column, stop computing when there is `0`, because the result bit will be `0`.

Example (included in test code below)

[image: Bitwise puzzle explained on an example]

Existing (iterative), rather slow (`O(n^2)`) code:

```
def solution(M, N):
    result = M
    for x in xrange(M, N):
        result &= x
    return result


def solution_sets(N):
    result = N[0]
    for x in N:
        result &= x
    return result


print solution(5, 7)  # 4
print solution(64, 128)  # 64
print solution(44, 55)  # 32
print solution_sets([60, 13, 12, 21])
```

It would be good if this solution was expandable to for example XOR operator.

I'm asking for some ideas on how to start implementing this in the Python language and maximize performance.

Thanks!

Comment: You are unlikely to improve upon the performance of bitwise operations on integers, particularly if you write it in Python.

Comment: Even if there is a function that lets you AND multiple numbers, your CPU can likely only AND 2 numbers at a time, making your "efficient" function still O(n^2) at the CPU instruction level.

Comment: What makes you think your algorithm is O(n^2)?  It's actually O(n).  You can eliminate 1 iteration by using "xrange(M+1,N)" to avoid performing "result = M & M" on the first iteration.  You can also stop early if result equals zero.  It would still be O(n), though.  It seems like you are working on a homework problem that you might be approaching in other than the prescribed way.

Comment: Thinking about it, you could possibly solve the `M, N` case analytically, and therefore write a function to calculate the answer in `O(1)`.

Comment: I'm also baffled by your (apparent) claim that your current solution is O(n^2).  It's O(n), unless the number of bits in each number can grow with n.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would let Python worry about the optimization, this could be written trivially for a sequence using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions)

```
>>> functools.reduce(operator.and_, [60, 13, 12, 21])
4
```

Wrapping this in a function

```
def solution_sets(l):
    return functools.reduce(operator.and_, l)
```

---

Using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), to do this 1000000 times took 0.758 seconds in the following environment:

> **Python IDLE 3.4.1** (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   **Processor** Intel Core i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70 GHz
>   **Memory** 16.0 GB
>   **OS** 64-bit Windows 7

```
setup = '''
import functools
import operator

def solution_sets(l):
    return functools.reduce(operator.and_, l)'''

>>> timeit.timeit('solution_sets([60, 13, 12, 21])', setup)
0.7582756285383709
```